# Service haproxy error

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability

I want to configure Haproxy for outgoing mail load balancing.
my configuration file /etc/haproxy.cfg is.

```
global
        maxconn     4096 # Total Max Connections. This is dependent on ulimit
        daemon
        nbproc      4 # Number of processing cores. Dual Dual-core Opteron is 4 cores for example.

defaults
        mode       tcp

listen smtp_proxy 199.83.95.71:25
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        balance roundrobin # Load Balancing algorithm
        ## Define your servers to balance
        server r23.lbsmtp.org 74.117.x.x:25  weight 1 maxconn 512 check
        server r15.lbsmtp.org 199.71.x.x:25  weight 1 maxconn 512 check
```

And when i start service haproxy i get this error.

`Starting HAproxy: [ALERT] 244/172148 (7354) : cannot bind socket for proxy smtp_proxy. Aborting.`

Please tell me where i am doing mistake.help will appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting bind errors, you need to check whether another process is already listening on the same port 25. You can use:

```
$ sudo netstat -lnp | grep 25
```

Another possibility is that you are running the process with insufficient privileges. Binding on ports under 1024 requires root privilege.

Comment: thank u khaled now my haproxy is running but now i want to know how i authenticate haproxy to relay mails from it's node and how i submit mails to haproxy either via php application or another postfix.

Comment: @user128296: If you have something else to ask about, you can post a new question on this site if it is on-topic.